# I need a very simple PHP database front-end admin panel; a simple records editor for a specified table

Tags: php, crud

I am looking to add some dynamics to our corporate website. This is a secondary role so I'd rather not be spending a ton of time on it.

At this point, all I need is a simple PHP script where a non-technical user can pull up and manage the records in a MySQL table. There's only one table of data to be managed; it's just that it will be accessed and updated quite frequently.

I recall that Grails' default scaffolding feature has precisely this: list of entries with the ability to add, edit and delete, with no nonsense.

What would be the best tool to use for this? I would rather not be writing it from scratch, as this will take me quite some time.

It seems like the kind of thing that ought to exist somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [Xataface](http://xataface.com/). It's essentially a [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) interface to your db. It's straightforward to install, open source and can be styled to match your corporate intranet.

Comment: mark his answer as accepted then!

Answer (score 1):

for the db script, I recommend [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/). It requires sql knowledge to do complex things, but simple operations are made friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

phpMyAdmin is my go-to for backend stuff. I wonder if there's some kind of template facility available for making it prettier & simpler for my boss.

Comment: I should have noticed this the first time - if it's a non technical user, why are they manipulating the db directly, instead of through a custom UI that abstracts records into the things they represent?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for similar functionality of Rails, there is CakePHP, which can automatically generate code for scaffolded views to add, edit, view and delete records.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out https://github.com/laravella/crud

http://laravella.github.io/docs/

It is built on laravel, easy to install, endless possibilities.

Comment: it seems doesn't update recently.