# symfony2 propel crud generator

Tags: code-generation, symfony, crud, propel

Hi not sure why I cannot find an answer for this already im sure im not the first person that wants to do this.

Ive just started using symfony again after 4 years and Im trying to use symfony2 with propel. I have used propel for many yours and get on well with it so would like to continue using it.

In symfony 1.x there used to be crud generators I see there still is in symfony2 but only for doctrine. Is there any support and/or plugin available for easy crud generation for propel in symfony2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a generator bundle for Symfony2 and Propel: https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle
It works like symfony 1.x and it is event better ;)
And Propel is well integrated.

Cheers,
William

Comment: cool thanks not sure why I didn't come across that when I was searching. The notes on http://symfony2bundles.org don't mention that it supports propel I may have just glanced over this bundle.

Comment: It was hiding from both of us! http://symfony2bundles.org/cedriclombardot/AdmingeneratorUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I did some searching for this recently for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598862/simple-crud-generation/7599207#7599207) and found that Symfony2 may not yet have Propel admin/module generators. If you are starting a new project, can you use 1.3 or 1.4? Not as exciting as using the new stuff, I admit, but if the generator is not yet available...

Comment: thanks that's pretty much what I thought. For now I have created my very own very basic CrudController (without generator). and ill just have to do things the slightly hard way. but I would much rather user Symfony2 then one of the older versions.