# Is symfony2 production ready?

Tags: symfony1, symfony

I know that Symfony2 has been released, but is it production ready, or are they still finding and fixing so many bugs as to make it impractical?

How is performance in a production environment? Are there current benchmarks anywhere?

I'm looking to build an n-tier web site and am deciding on whether learning sf2 will be time well spent compared to just sticking with sf1.4.

What gaps are there in symfony2 - from what it seems there's no official admin generator. Is anything else missing?

Comment: They have a stable release. So yes, it's ready.

Comment: There are already lots of production sites built on top of Symfony 2. It also went through a security audit which costed 6000 euros, so it is already the most secure php 5.3 framework, no doubt about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have released a Symfony 2 based project that was featured in a major newspaper and did well. I'd deem it as production ready. I also did some load tests with jMeter and the man from the hosting company was impressed by the performance.

The only thing lacking IMO is the amount of tutorial and special articles that you have for Symfony 1. Nevertheless, I'll use Symfony 2 for all my future projects.

One slight problem at the moment could be the hosting companies: You absolutely need PHP 5.3 (most companies still offer 5.2 only) and a caching mechanism (APC or memcached) for maximum Doctrine 2 performance.

Comment: ok, i'll be hosting myself, so php version isn't a problem. that sounds good. thanks

Comment: I think Symfony2 isn't really aimed at shared host users, though I expect with some gentle coaxing that it would work on such a platform (1.x works fine on shared hosts). A decent VPS can be had now for a few USD/month, and anyone who can cope with writing a Symfony2 app can surely manage a Linux server :)

Answer (score 3):

Symfony2 is definitely production ready. The developers are just fixing minor bugs since the stable release. I know Fabien Potencier published some benchmark tests a while ago, but I can't find them. Maybe you'll have better luck. Anyway, I believe it's faster than any other framwork out there.

You're right when you say there isn't an official admin generator, but you can use [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master), which is absolutely awesome (but a little hard to get to work properly).

Comment: i saw the benchmarks last year... i couldn't find them again either.

Comment: Benchmarks? You shouldn't base your choice on that. Anyway, you can be sure that Symfony 2 is the fastest php framework ever. It only loads what it needs, it caches everything (eg: config files, routes, etc, everything is compiled to plain php), and can has native support to interact with lots of other libraries like YUI Compressor or Varnish, to make your site fast as hell

Answer (score 0):

See here regarding the admin generator - apparently there is one :)

[symfony2 propel crud generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796715/symfony2-propel-crud-generator)

Comment: Use [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master) which is half-official and very, very cool.